# Replace all characters in a string after/including a space

Tags: excel, vba

I want to replace all of the characters in a string that come after a space, and then I would like to get rid of the space as well. Lets say the word was "Throw Baseball", I want my program to return me "Throw" and that's it. I'm using some code that I found online but It does not seem to work and keeps calling Example String an invalid Variable. ANy help would be greatly appreciated

```
Dim ExampleString As String
ExampleString = "Throw Baseball"
Dim StringReplace As String
Dim CharReplaceCounter As String
CharReplaceCounter = 0
Dim I AS Integer
I=0
While (ExampleString.Characters(CharReplaceCounter).Text <> " ")
CharReplaceCounter = CharReplaceCounter + 1
Wend

While(I<CharReplaceCounter)
StringReplace.Characters(CharReplaceCounter).Text = ExampleString.Characters(CharReplaceCounter).Text
I=I+1
Wend
```

It should give me Throw for the StringReplace string, however it does not.

Comment: You could just use `Split(ExampleString, " ")(0)`

Comment: So I changed it to Split(ExampleString, " ")(0), and made it equal an array, but when I try to access the cell in the array it says error expected array. So my calling it is ArrayTest(0), and it does not like this? did I split it wrong?

Comment: try this : finalstring = Trim(Mid(ExampleString, 1, InStr(1, ExampleString, " ", vbBinaryCompare)))

Comment: Split(ExampleString, " ") returns a Variant Array. Split(ExampleString, " ")(0) returns a Variant.

Comment: `ExampleString.Characters` ?? This doesn't look much like Excel VBA..?

Comment: Thank you Gareth, that works I didn't know that that returned a variant, and thank you Shashi Singh that worked as well!

Comment: I tried to find some code CLR as I am very new to VBA and this is what the internet came up with. I must have searched something completely wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim ExampleString As String
ExampleString = "Throw Baseball"
If InStr(ExampleString, " ") Then Debug.Print Left(ExampleString, InStr(ExampleString, " ") - 1)
```

or

```
Dim ExampleString As String
ExampleString = "Throw Baseball"
Debug.Print Split(ExampleString, " ")(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `InStr()` to determine the position of the first space, then just keep `Left()` to one position short of the space, such that:

```
Left(FullString,InStr(FullString," ")-1)
```

Thanks @CLR for the correction.  Typed it up off head and started my `InStr` number of arguements in the `Left`

Comment: It gives me Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment. I did TestString = Left(ExampleString, " ", InStr(ExampleString, " ")-1).

Comment: I think @Cyril meant `Left(ExampleString, InStr(ExampleString, " ") - 1)`

Comment: @Hakon fixed.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks @CLR (more characters)